# Nested loop conversion to recursive function in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I can't seem to figure out properly how to convert this nested loop into a recursive function in Java?

```
ArrayList<House[]> houseList = new ArrayList<House[]>();
        for (House h0 : houses) {
            if (h0.getPosition() == 0) {
                for (House h1 : houses) {
                    if (h1.getPosition() == 1) {
                        for (House h2 : houses) {
                            if (h2.getPosition() == 2) {
                                for (House h3 : houses) {
                                    if (h3.getPosition() == 3) {
                                        for (House h4 : houses) {
                                            if (h4.getPosition() == 4) {
                                                House[] list = new House[]{h0,h1,h2,h3,h4};
                                                houseList.add(list);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

At this moment the houses object contains 133 elements, and the combinations given after the nested loop execution gives me 9810801 possibilities.
How would this has to be written recursively to be usable for more than 5 times?

Comment: It will simplify the problem considerably simpler and probably run faster if you first split the list of houses by position. E.g. use a Map<Integer, ArrayList<House>>.  Then the recursion is very simple.  Also, wrap this in a Builder class so you don't have to pass a gajillion parameters.

Comment: @Gene I am thinking about how to improve my answer with your suggestion. It seems that the sequence of House with position is important. For example, the result of a input [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] will be different from [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]. I am pretty sure my answer still have a lot of space to improve. Would you mind to share your thoughts?

Comment: @Wilson Okay I added some code to show what I mean. It produces the same sequence as the OP's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of `House` with position with either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Let me use a annotation of `H{i}` to represent a House with position i which 0 <= i <= 4.

If your input list is

```
[ H{0}, H{1}, H{2}, H{3}, H'{3}, H{4}, H'{4} ]
```

which `H'` is another house

the result is

```
[
  [ H{0}, H{1}, H{2}, H{3}, H{4} ], 
  [ H{0}, H{1}, H{2}, H{3}, H'{4} ],
  [ H{0}, H{1}, H{2}, H'{3}, H{4} ],
  [ H{0}, H{1}, H{2}, H'{3}, H'{4} ],
]
```

This give me following information:

1. When iterate to `H{3}`, it find a `House` with next position, i.e. 4.
2. When iterate to `H{4}`, it will create the 1st list and store the houses with a position of 0, 1, 2, 3 iterated previously.
3. After reach `H{4}`, it will find another `House` with position 4, i.e. `H'{4}`, and create 2nd list and store the houses iterate previously except `H{4}`.
4. When reach the end of the list, it is back to `H'{3}` and iterate the list again to create 3rd and 4th list.

From #2, we know that:

1. We need to create a list to store the `House` if house position = 4
2. There should be a `buffer` to store the `House` with position 0, 1, 2, 3, iterated before. `buffer[0]` will store `H{0}`, `buffer[1]` will store `H{2}`, etc.

From #3, we know that:

If reach `House` with position 4, the list will further iterate until reach the end of the list.

We can have a base function as follows:

```
public static List<House[]> foo(House[] houses, List<House> buffer) {
    List<House[]> list = new ArrayList<House[]>();
    for (House house : houses) {
        if (house.getPosition() == buffer.size()) {
            buffer.add(house);
            if (house.getPosition() == 4) { 
                list.add(buffer.toArray(new House[buffer.size()]));
                buffer.remove(buffer.size() - 1);
            } 
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

What the above do?

```
for (House house : houses) {
    if (house.getPosition() == buffer.size()) {
        buffer.add(house);
```

At the very beginning, `buffer` is empty with size = 0. If it find a `House` with position 0, it will be stored into the `buffer` and the `buffer` size becomes 1. When the list iterate to next `House` with position = 1 (the `buffer` size), it will be stored. Otherwise, find another `House` that match the condition.

```
if (house.getPosition() == 4) { 
    list.add(buffer.toArray(new House[buffer.size()]));
    buffer.remove(buffer.size() - 1);
}
```

As mentioned, a list will be created to store the `House` in the buffer if there is a `House` with position 4. `buffer.remove(buffer.size() - 1)` is to remove the last `House` with position 4 such that another `House` can be stored into `buffer`.

So far, no recursive call is in our function since the case for `House` with position 4 do not need it.

Let's look back to #1 and #4. We know that:

If reach a `House` with position other than 4, it find a `House` with next position and create a list when iterate to `House` with position 4.

It means that our base function will be called if a `House` with position other than 4. So, we can modify our function as follows:

```
public static List<House[]> foo(House[] houses, List<House> buffer) {
    List<House[]> list = new ArrayList<House[]>();
    for (House house : houses) {
        if (house.getPosition() == buffer.size()) {
            buffer.add(house);
            if (house.getPosition() == 4) { // base case, no recursive call
                list.add(buffer.toArray(new House[buffer.size()]));
                buffer.remove(buffer.size() - 1);
            } else { // recursive case
                list.addAll(foo(houses, buffer));
            }
        }
    }
    if (buffer.size() > 0) {
        buffer.remove(buffer.size() - 1);
    }
    return list;
}
```

In summary, we have 2 case for the problem. One is the base case to handle `House` with position 4 and another case is to handle `House` with position other than 4 which need a recursive call.

Recursive function normally divide problem into cases. The function calls itself recursively on a smaller list of `Houses` until reaching the base case. Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Since @Wilson asked how I'd do it, here's a way that will work for any assortment of `position` values in the input, even if they're not contiguous. Call with something like:

```
List<House[]> houseTupleList = new HouseTupleListBuilder()
    .addAll(houses)
    .build();
```

The output tuples will contain values for the populated positions in ascending order.

Note that if a position number is missing entirely in the input (e.g. in the example there were only houses with positions 0,1,3,4), this code will happily produce tuples using only the present values (e.g. in my example, they would be 4-tuples).  If you don't want that, you should call the builder's method `expectPosition(i)` for all expected positions `i`. Then if the input is lacking any position, the output will be empty, just as the OP's version.

```
class HouseTupleListBuilder {
  private final NavigableMap<Integer, List<House>> housesByPosition = new TreeMap<>();

  HouseTupleListBuilder addAll(Collection<House> houses) {
    for (House house : houses) {
      expectPosition(house.getPosition());
      housesByPosition.get(house.getPosition()).add(house);
    }
    return this;
  }

  HouseTupleListBuilder expectPosition(int i) {
    housesByPosition.putIfAbsent(i, new ArrayList<>());
    return this;
  }

  List<House[]> build() { return new TupleEnumerator().enumeration(); }

  private class TupleEnumerator {
    private final Map<Integer, House> houseByPosition = new TreeMap<>();
    private final List<House[]> tuples = new ArrayList<>();

    private void enumerateFor(NavigableSet<Integer> positions) {
      if (positions.isEmpty()) {
        tuples.add(houseByPosition.values().toArray(new House[0]));
        return;
      }
      int first = positions.first();
      for (House house : housesByPosition.get(first)) {
        houseByPosition.put(first, house);
        enumerateFor(positions.tailSet(first, false));
      }
    }

    private List<House[]> enumeration() {
      enumerateFor(housesByPosition.navigableKeySet());
      return tuples;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your thought! It looks interesting. I 'll definitely have a deep look into it

Answer (score 0):

Acctually @Wilson answer wasn't correct after all. After a bit of trial and error I came up with a solution myself. Here's the recursive function of the code:

```
private void recursiveFunc(ArrayList<House> houses,ArrayList<House[]> resultList,House[] tempList, int pos, int maxPos) {
        for (House h : houses) {
            if (h.getPosition() == pos) {
                tempList[pos] = h;
                if (pos < maxPos-1) {
                    recursiveFunc(houses,resultList,tempList,pos+1,maxPos);
                }
                else if (pos == maxPos-1) {
                    House[] resultHouse = new House[maxPos];
                    for (int i=0; i<maxPos; i++) resultHouse[i] = tempList[i];
                    resultList.add(resultHouse);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And I execute the function as follows:

```
recursiveFunc(houses,solutionList,new House[numberOfPositions],0,numberOfPositions);
```

Comment: Glad to hear you came up a solution. Look likes that you forgot to copy the `tempList` into the `resultList` and this will cause your `resultList` contain a list of the same array. You mentioned that my answer wasn't correct after all. I have tried to compare the result with my code and your original function and the result are the same. Can you tell me why you think my answer is incorrect?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, my bad. You're code does actually produce the same results. First time I copied it, I must have implemented something incorrectly, because it gave different results, but yes, your code is indeed correct as well. I give you an upvote to your answer for that.

Comment: It is okay. I just don't want leave my wrong answer in SO. About copy an array, you can also try `System.arraycopy()` or `Arrays.copyOf()`;)

Comment: @AndrisGauračs It's pretty brutal not to accept Wilson's answer after 1) you provided incomplete code in the question, 2) he put in a lot of effort to build a working solution, 3) you incorrectly stated his solution was wrong, only to reverse, and 4) clearly based your code on his. Hope I never need to work on a project with you...

Comment: @Gene I am deeply sorry for being so rude. I have changed the correct answer to Wilson's.